# Is it possible to deploy multiple modules respectively using one build job with multiple modules via Jenkins?

Tags: maven, deployment, build, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use jenkins to build one job contains multiple modules and deploy those multiple modules respectively on a box. The structure of the simplified maven dependencies shown as below:

```
|-- A
|   `-- pom.xml
              |-- B
              |   `-- pom.xml
              |-- C
              |   `-- pom.xml
              |-- D
              |   `-- pom.xml
```

I successfully get 3 release packages for B, C, D. However, it turns out jenkins do not support to deploy those 3 packages respectively when I denoted the module I would like to deploy in each individual deploy job. Instead, there is only one build id for one build job, and only A is legitimate deliverable for the jenkins deployment. Any thoughts or workaround except using chained build jobs to build multiple times?

Comment: You should define "deploy". Do you mean the Maven "deploy" phase? If so, they get executed for each module when your Jenkins build job is configured to execute e.g. instead of "mvn install" do a "mvn deploy" and it gets executed for all modules.

Comment: The jenkins build job just produce one build id at one time, the question I am asking is how we could use that one build id to do the deploy(as I stated in the question, deploy those multiple modules respectively on a box(unix).)for each specific nested sub-modules instead of the parent artifact which the build id stands for.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly clear whether you are looking for **filtering** the "jars" i.e artifacts being pushed out in "deploy" phase. If you are looking for filtering you can try out setting up exclude patterns or include patterns ( Note - we are using artifactory plugin )
A screenshot for Post Build Actions -

[image]

Comment: I am assuming the examples you are using is for the scenario that all the artifacts are on the same level, then you could exclude some of them out. But my problem is that I would like the sub-modules (which are one level under the artifact(parent) being built) being deployed respectively instead of the parent.

Comment: The war module module artifact is one level below parent.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *maven-deploy-plugin* to automatically deploy all of your modules (no matter on which level they are) to your remote Maven repository.

It is [easy to use](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html), just add a `<distributionManagement>` section into your parent pom, configure the `<server>` part in your settings.xml if necessary and add the `deploy` goal to your Jenkins build job.

The *maven-deploy-plugin* will be executed automatically for each module of your reactor project.